# Delete whitespaces vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete all whitespaces in a range and got the following code

```
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim cleanString2 As String
Set rng2 = ContactData.Range("AR2:AR" & lRow)
rng2.Value = Application.Trim(rng2)
For j = 2 To lRow
    cleanString2 = ContactData.Range("AR" & j).Value
    cleanString2 = Replace(cleanString2, Chr(10), "")
    ContactData.Range("AR" & j).Value = cleanString2
Next j
```

I got and equivalent code with same variables and everything just **without** the **2** in the **variable names** the code works, but the other code goes for colum **A** instead of **AR**, can anybody help me with finding the bug?
**Thanks!**

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cleanString As String
Set rng = ContactData.Range("A2:A" & lRow)
rng.Value = Application.Trim(rng)
For i = 2 To lRow
    cleanString = ContactData.Range("A" & i).Value
    cleanString = Replace(cleanString, Chr(10), "")
    ContactData.Range("A" & i).Value = cleanString
Next i
```

this is the working code, below a picture of the variable values while debugging:

[image: Debugging Code]

Comment: What is the error and on which line? BTW, you don't need a loop: `ContactData.Range("A2:A" & lRow).Replace chr(10), vbnullstring, xlpart`

Comment: there is no error @Rory that is my problem, it runs through fine, but just does not delete the whitespaces

Comment: Can you try with `cleanString = Replace(cleanString, " ", "")`?

Comment: `Chr(10)` is a linefeed character, not whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than do it row by row you could replace all whitespace in one hit.

The problem you're finding is that you're referencing different ranges.
The original code states:
`Set rng = ContactData.Range("A2:AR" & lRow)`

Your code has:
`Set rng = ContactData.Range("A2:A" & lRow)` - missing the ref to column `AR`.

You could use the below code to remove the whitespace (`Chr(32`).  As @Rory said - Chr(10) is a linefeed.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = 15
    Set rng = ContactData.Range("A2:AR" & lRow)

    rng.Replace What:=Chr(32), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Comment: Was just re-reading the question - it says `Set rng2 = ContactData.Range("AR2:AR" & lRow)` and I put `Set rng = ContactData.Range("A2:AR" & lRow)`.  Could've sworn I copied and pasted... early in the morning though.

Comment: that is just a breeze and it boosted my perfomance so much. Sir you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code, the problem is that you are hoping that:

```
cleanString = Replace(cleanString, Chr(10), "")
```

would remove the whitespaces. `Chr(10)` is not a whitespace as per the ASCII table. Thus, the easiest way is probably to go like this:

```
cleanString = Replace(cleanString, " ", "")
```

If this does not work, as a workaround try this:

```
Public Sub RemoveSpaceInString()    
    Dim myCell As Range            
    For Each myCell In Selection
        myCell = Trim(myCell)
        myCell = Replace(myCell, vbTab, "")
        myCell = Replace(myCell, " ", "")
        myCell = Replace(myCell, Chr(160), "")
    Next myCell    
End Sub
```

It uses `Selection`, because it was intended to be used outside working code, as a "format-helping" tool. However, if it works, it would be quite easy to write it inside your code.

Comment: oh my god, I can't believe I have been so dump, the code with Chr(10) only deleted the leading and last whitespaces. Thank you so much!